# Javascript: Do a GET request and parse Response

Tags: javascript, parsing, get

I'm writing a MacOs widget that have to explain the bus arrive retrive info from a website like this:

http://www.5t.torino.it/5t/it/trasporto/arrivi-fermata.jsp

i have to make a Get request and parse the response.. i try with:

```
var xmlHttp = null;
var theUrl = "http://m.gtt.to.it/m/it/arrivi.jsp?n=876";
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET",theUrl,false);
xmlHttp.send( null );
xmlDoc=xmlHttp.responseXML;
```

but i don't know the structure of document how i can do to navigate it?

Comment: I think you are missing "onreadystatechange" handler. It will be called on getting the response. You can perform required operation then. If you don't know the structure, write the response to console or alert it or append to a div/HTML element.

Comment: this is the code in the function i know that i need an handler..

Answer (score 0):

> but i don't know the structure of document how i can do to navigate it?

You either walk the tree and poke at the note type and node name of the nodes in it, or you examine the XML document manually in order to learn the structure.

Answer (score -1):

It is better to make your Ajax call asynchronous imo by doing:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, true);
```

This will prevent your users from interfering an annoying "blocked" period on your website.

If you do so you have to add a `onreadystatechange` handler so you can parse the incoming data there and display the data you want to display.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      var content = xmlhttp.responseText;
      //Parse your content here...
   }
}
```

Clearly you have to know what data you are retrieving to be able to parse it. But for that you can just analyze the `responseText` and find the elements that always contain your data. Then simply retrieve the values from those `<html>` tags and display it accordingly.

For instance if you want to retrieve the data in a `<label>` with id set to **arrival-time** do:

```
content.getElementById('arrival-time').innerHTML;
```

Comment: Horrible though it is, the request is set to synchronous so watching for the ready state to change isn't needed. HTMLElementNodes don't have a `text` method.

Comment: I changed the text to innerHTML() ages ago. Please refresh your page before commenting. :)

Comment: `innerHTML` is not a method either.

Comment: thank a lot for the reply but i can't visualized the structure, there is a method to store the xml-reply on disk?

Comment: @LuigiTagliamonte What do you mean you can't visualize the structure? Just analyze the HTML you retrieve and find the elements that contain values you want to use.

Comment: @Jules — No, [it isn't](http://jsfiddle.net/R26P3/1/), and now you've edited the answer to remove the `()`, you aren't trying to use it as such any more.

Comment: There is a library that trasform all the tag in the HTML response in a DOM three?